# I try to add a New Texture to one of the scuplt brush but it doesn't work

Tags: texturing

I'm learning Blender. I use a book where I'm told to add an new texture to Scuptldraw, I select new and the preview of the texture is black and my brush doesn't work anymore. It's the same for any brush of the scuplt mode : I can use the default texture, when I add one I have no file browser opening, it becomes all black and doesn't work anymore.
Help !!!

Comment: If the preview of the texture becomes black it means the texture doesn't have any information (no image is assigned to it). And since black color technically is 0 it won't draw because something + 0 won't change anything at all. Did you try to change assigned texture to sculpt brush by adding some image to it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can choose the file to use in your texture in the properties editor, Texture tab:

[image]

Comment: You can also use any of the built in procedural textures as a brush, choosing them from the drop down there where it says 'Type: Image or Movie'. It is very easy to use them with different mappings in the texture brush settings in the tool bar, like View, Tiled, 3D, Stencil, etc.